# Application java with socket

Tags: java

I have a problem with the socket in java: I have a server on the desktop PC that I've a ServerSocket object Instantiated such:

```
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

where "port" is a number of port.

This serverSocket accept a client. This client is another application java that runs on another desktop PC that connected to the same net of the server PC. In this application java, I Instantiated a Socket object which connects with local IP of server PC (example: 192.168.1.11) and port of serverSocket. When I run the server and the client, the client does not connect to the server. If I run the server and the client on the same desktop PC, the client manages to connect to the server.

I was thinking of a problem with the firewall configuration but I did not manage to solve it. Help me please.

This is code of server:

```
//I will accept one client
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(19999);
Socket client = server.accept();                
new Thread(new ManagerConnectionThread(client)).start(); //this thread manage the requests
```

ManagerConnectionThread is a class that manage the communication between server and client:

```
//This code is on the server
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
```

This is code of client:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.11"), 19999); //192.168.1.11 is IP of "server" pc
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add client and server source code?

Comment: If the connection can be established on the same computer but not on different ones, then it is likely a firewall problem. What OS runs on your server? And what firewall?

Comment: @vanje that's is absolutely correct.

Comment: on my server run windows 10.The application run in eclipse neon 3. I make this work for study. The firewall is the default of windows 10. I also tried to connect with browser on the other pc but nothing.

Comment: "I also tried to connect with browser on the other pc but nothing" on port 19999 or just generally? Are you sure that the IP is correct?'

Comment: @Kayaman I used the browser of another pc connected to the same network with this url:  192.168.1.11:19999 where 192.168.1.11 is the ip of server pc...(obviously "local" IP that is inside my network). Anyway, I tried to add a rule of firewall for eclipse on my server both in "inbound connection" and in "outbound connection", but nothing :(

Comment: `netstat -aon | findstr %YOUR_PORT%` to find out if you actually listening on server (LISTENING should appear against your port).
try to use `telnet %SERVER_IP% %PORT%` command (you may google how to enable telnet).

for windows 10 install Wireshark (with winpcap), select your network interface and filter `tcp.port == 19999` on server, and same for client; you should see then if any packets actually come to your port.

it will get much easier if you get into proper diagnostic tools fort this kind of tasks.

Comment: Thank all, it's a problem of windows firewall, I reset rules and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a router involved? if yes you will need to configure some port-forwarding and try to access via the external address, meaning that you will try to connect through the router that will point to your machine.

Also, you might need to do some tweaking with the firewall, at some point I was doing something similar for school, but as a server, I was using a Linux based OS so the procedure might be different, but I definitely needed to allow in/out for the port that I was using.

you might find some answers in this post which is similar 
[Java Chat with TCP/IP over LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662866/java-chat-with-tcp-ip-over-lan)

Edit: I found my old homework, and I have definitely used the external address (especially because I wanted to access it from school, while the server was home) so I would connect to my external address of the laptop and then in the router's settings I would forward the port that I was using to the server, in the server allowing incoming traffic for the specific port.